# Icon not shown with g_file_new_for_uri

Tags: c, gtk3, gio

all. I'm trying to display an icon in my notification, see relevant code:

```
GIcon* gicon_from_path (const gchar* path)
{
    GFile *file = NULL;
    GIcon *tmp = NULL;
    
    file = g_file_new_for_path (path);
    tmp = g_file_icon_new (file);
    
    g_object_unref (file);
    return tmp;
}

GIcon* gicon_from_resource (const gchar* res)
{
    GFile *file = NULL;
    GIcon *tmp = NULL;
    
    file = g_file_new_for_uri (res);
    tmp = g_file_icon_new (file);
    
    g_object_unref (file);
    return tmp;
}

void send_notification (GApplication *application)
{
    GNotification *notification;
    GIcon *icon;

    //icon = gicon_from_path (PACKAGE_DATADIR "/gtk3-demo-icon_32.png");
    icon = gicon_from_resource ("resource:///button/icons/tray.png");
    notification = g_notification_new ("Hola");
    g_notification_set_body (notification, "Probando");
    if (icon)
    {
        g_print ("Have icon");
        g_notification_set_icon (notification, icon);
    }
    g_application_send_notification (application, "lunch-is-ready", notification);
    
    g_object_unref (icon);
    g_object_unref (notification);
}

void on_clicked (GtkWidget *self, gpointer user_data)
{
    PMYDATA pD = user_data; // my app data
    send_notification (G_APPLICATION (pD->app));
}
```

If I use **gicon_from_path** the icon is showed as expected. But with **gicon_from_resource** not only the icon is not showed, I get this messages:

```
(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.627: g_variant_new_take_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.627: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.627: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.628: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.628: g_variant_builder_add_value: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->expected_type || g_variant_is_of_type (value, GVSB(builder)->expected_type)' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.628: g_variant_builder_end: assertion 'GVSB(builder)->offset >= GVSB(builder)->min_items' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.628: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.628: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gtk3_single:3256): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:18:23.628: g_variant_builder_add_value: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->expected_type || g_variant_is_of_type (value, GVSB(builder)->expected_type)' failed
```

In both cases, I can see the message **Have icon** from `g_print`. So I guess is something in `g_file_new_for_uri`. Btw, this is my .gresource.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- to use with gtk3 -->
<gresources>
    <gresource prefix="/main/icons/">
        <file alias="16x16/apps/gtk3_single.png">gtk3-demo-icon_16.png</file>
        <file alias="32x32/apps/gtk3_single.png">Cat-icon_32.png</file>
        <file alias="48x48/apps/gtk3_single.png">cat-food-hearts-icon_48.png</file>
    </gresource>
    <gresource prefix="/button/icons">
        <file alias="home.png">Home-icon_24.png</file>
        <file alias="tray.png">gtk3-demo-icon_32.png</file>
    </gresource>
    <gresource prefix="/menu/icons">
        <file alias="quit">Actions-application-exit-icon_20.png</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>
```

My OS is Archlinux using gtk3 3.24.34. So, any help or ideas?

Comment: You can try debugging the critical warnings using `G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals gdb ./my-program` and getting a backtrace on the first critical. You should also make sure that your resources are correctly linked into the program and registered at startup. You can do this by looking in the resources view of gtk-inspector, runnable using `GTK_DEBUG=interactive ./my-program`.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall, well I can see other icons extract from the resource which indeed is embeded into my program

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. You can see other icons but not `tray.png`?

Comment: @PhilipWithnall, correct. All icons are show but noy tray.png as GIcon. I use tray.png as gtkbutton image to test path error, but no, is show as expected.

Comment: I can’t think of a way to debug this further if you’ve tried both my suggestions above. The next step would be for you to provide a minimal reproducible example, including the build commands you’re using to compile and link everything.